yarnをインストールしようとするとエラーが出力されます。しかし、yarn --versionというコマンドを打ち込むとバージョンが出力されます。
タイトルの通りになります。yarnをインストールしようとすると下記のようなエラーが出力されます。
私はReactのインストールのためにyarnをインストールしようとしていますが、
npm install --global yarn コマンドをターミナルに入力するとエラーが出ます。
しかし、yarnは yarn --version コマンドを打ち込むと
下記のようにバージョンが出力されます。
「1.22.22」
yarnはインストールされていますでしょうか？
https://qiita.com/rspmharada7645/items/25c496aee87973bcc7a5
具体的なエラー
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /Users/ユーザ名/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/98/20
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/ユーザ名/.npm"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/ユーザ名/.npm/_logs/2024-05-21T07_47_23_816Z-debug-0.log
tomato@kazuhonoMacBook-Pro ~ % npm i sass --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /Users/tomato/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/98/20
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/ユーザ名/.npm"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/ユーザ名/.npm/_logs/2024-05-21T07_47_44_510Z-debug-0.log

補足情報
Macのバージョン：14.3.1（23D60）
nodeのバージョン：v20.13.1
yarnのバージョン:1.22.22

エラーメッセージに修正方法が手順として表示されているように見えます。それに従って作業すれば良いのでは？ あるいは単にsudoでやってみるとか？ yarn とは？（＋ Mac に yarn を導入する手順）

yarnのコマンドが使えるので、自己解決したと思われます。ご回答ありがとうございました。
